# Assign a value to character named variable with index

Tags: r, character

I know we can use `assign` to assign values to a character name vector. For example

```
assign("target",1:5)
```

However, if we want to change the 1st element of the `target`(`target` can be a vector/matrix/list), how should we do that? `target` here can also be a matrix, so we can change one element, one row or one column.
I want to do something like

```
target[1] <- 99
```

if I use

```
assign("target[1]",99)
```

it will only generate a new object named `target[1]` and value is 99. Here is a simple and trial example

```
# This function is meaningless, just used to show my situation
# variable_name is a character
example_function <- function(variable_name){
    assign(variable_name,1:5)

    if(rnorm(1)>1){
    variable_name[1] <- 99 #This will not work and I just need some function to achive this purpose
    }
}
example_function("justAname")
```

Comment: `target[1] <- 99` works fine... What's the problem?

Comment: the variable name is generate by a function inside, so we do not know the exactly variable name when we want to change one of the element of that variable

Comment: What function `assign()` does is create a new variable with first argument as its name. This means after `assign("target",1:5)`, there will exist a new variable called `target` with values 1 to 5. If you do `print(target)` you will see your new variable. Thus, doing `target[1] <- 99` will treat `target` as a normal variable, allowing you to do the assignment. Try it, it works

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I will update my post to illustrate my situation.

Comment: `replace(eval(as.name(variable_name)), 1, 99)` possibly

Comment: Thanks, @RichScriven, it is a solution. However, my situation is more complex, `target` can be a vector/matrix/list.

Comment: It works with those too.  `replace(matrix(1:6, 2), cbind(c(1, 2), c(2, 2)), 99)`

Comment: From help page of `replace`, it said `x is unchanged: remember to assign the result.` Looks like `replace` does not change the value of `target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach you could use the `[<-` function.

```
f = function(variable_name){
  assign(variable_name,1:5)
  if(rnorm(1)>1){
    `[<-`(eval(as.name(variable_name)),i = 1, value = 99)
  }
  get(variable_name)
}
```

This should also work with matrices

```
f_mat = function(variable_name){
  assign(variable_name,matrix(1:25,nrow = 5))
  if(rnorm(1)>1){
    `[<-`(eval(as.name(variable_name)),i = 1, j = , value = 99) # for 1st row
    # `[<-`(eval(as.name(variable_name)),i = , j = 1, value = 99) # for 1st col
    #specify i and j for ith row jth column
  }
  get(variable_name)
}
```

and lists similarly.